# как правильно сменить название пакета приложения?

Tags: java, android

У меня такая проблема, мне нужно было работать с камерой я нашел подходящий пример по работе с камерой и начал его кастить под себя, дописал кучу классов и вот теперь я хочу сменить название пакета в манифесте. Никогда раньше этого не делал поэтому боюсь, что то упустить.

Вот, что я делаю
1) Делаю в самом манифесте рефактор этой строчки

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
---> package="ru.newzon.room"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
```

и вроде как рефактор проходит успешно, но я заметил, что дальше в манифесте в разделах

```
<permission
<uses-permission
<application
<receiver
```

осталось название старого пакета, я так понимаю мне нужно менять это все вручную и рефактор на это не влияет? И второе, нужно ли еще, что то учесть при смене имени пакета?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И когда я делаю рефактор прям на этом пакете который остался не измененным, то во первых я получаю вот такое предупреждение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и во вторых я ожидаю, что все полностью прежнее название вот это:

```
com.example.android.camera2basic
```

будет изменено на :

```
ru.newzon.room
```

но у меня меняется название не все полностью a только название последней дириктории и получается вот так :

```
com.example.android.room
```

как развернуть эти точки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас в java файлах название пакета поменялось? должно быть нет. Вам нужно в левой панели тоже изменить сам пакет через рефакторинг

Comment: На самом деле можно не менять. Но тогда нужно избавится от сокращений в путях в манифесте.

Comment: @Saidolim я добавил описание вопроса, можете подсказать как правильно сделать?

Comment: @pavel Павел я ночек и наверное поэтому не совсем понял, что вы имели ввиду, можете объяснить? Я кстати добавил описание вопроса

Comment: Есть разные варианты как это сделать, можно вообще ничего не трогать в самом коде ( и не рефакторить) и посеять только манифест, для этого ВЕЗДЕ где путь начинается с . нужно эту точку заменить на старое имя пакета. В коде нужно будет только подставить импорт R файла, остальное должно и так работать. А ещё ест.ь специальный файл на Питоне который это делает, могу скинуть.

Comment: @pavel Да, но если следовать первому решению, то я так понимаю имена самих пакетов останутся... Мне очень не хочется, чтоб в моем проекте были другие имена. Файл на Питоне который вы говорите может сделать полный рефактор? И он работает без побочных эффектов? А инструкция есть? А то я могу чет сделать не так)

Comment: А какая разница какие имена лежат в вашем приложении?  Главное это имя пакета.

Comment: Ок, согласен. Я только, что поменял в манифесте имя пакета и потом по всех java файлах поменял путь к R классу и при запуске у меня показало такую ошибку Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.android.camera2basic/.Welcome2 } Error type 3 Error: Activity class {com.example.android.camera2basic/com.example.android.camera2basic.Welcome2} does not exist. Что бы это могло означать?

Comment: @pavel Как вы считаете, что это может означать?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko именно это и значит, всё что начинается с . в манифесте надо развернуть.

Comment: @pavel я извиняюсь конечно, но я все равно не понял, все что начинается с точки заменить на старое имя файла? Во первых у меня пол манифеста начинается с точки(рисунок приложил к вопросу), а во вторых что значит развернуть(заменить на старое имя файла) ? Как я должен развернуть эти точки?)) Можете пожалуйста скинуть какой нибудь скриншот или пример?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko именно, везде где была . вначале нужно написать СТАРОЕ имя пакета, я вроде бы это где-то выше и писал.

Comment: @pavel Да все вроде как заработало, всего лишь нужно было точки поменять на старое название пакета)) Но Сервис теперь не хочет работать...